# How to call a server-side function from javascript in MVC?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am doing amendments in my MVC application in order to disallow users to open more than one tab/ window within a single session.
I am taking reference of [**this article (click here)**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35859/Detect-and-prevent-multiple-windows-or-tab-usage-i?msg=4506432#xx4506432xx) in order to do that.
This article is written for asp.net whereas I need to implement this feature for ASP.NET MVC.
I think all this should be possible in MVC, however, I am not sure what should I do to re-write this

```
if(window.name != "<%=GetWindowName()%>")
```

GetWindowName() is a function I have created in my Controller, and it returns a value of "WindowName" key from Session object. How can I read its value in above javascript?

Comment: Use Ajax !!! My apprentice ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write a controller method for that:

```
public ActionResult GetWindowName()
{
  Session["WindowName"] = 
    Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "");
  return Json(Session["WindowName"].ToString());
}
```

Then call it through ajax:

```
$.get('@Url.Action("GetWindowName")', function(data){
    if(window.name != data) {
        // do what you need to do here
    }
})
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use ajax for that (jQuery):

```
$.get('@Url.Action("GetWindowName")', function(result){
    if(window.name != result)
    //...
});
```

This is razor syntax...